# Catch all exceptions without begin-rescue

Tags: ruby, backtrace

I am trying to find the ideal way to catch all exceptions for the purpose of formatting the backtrace output.

I should mention that the intention is to have a simple gem that can just be `required` and provide backtrace that is easier to read. So `begin`...`rescue` is not an option.

So far, I have found two methods to do it, each with its own issues:

1. Using [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/TracePoint.html), like I [did here](https://github.com/DannyBen/pretty_trace/blob/aff6ddb9d27609d3926cf8051246b8238efcdf63/lib/pretty_trace/handler.rb#L21).
2. Using [`at_exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit), like I [did here](https://github.com/DannyBen/pretty_trace/blob/476f3f47897be983eef2108baa9c47a8d4b1e234/lib/pretty_trace/handler.rb#L11).

The `TracePoint` method gave me less flexibility than needed, and with the `at_exit` method, I feel that I am abusing this method, especially since I must also use `exit!` to prevent the original backtrace from printing.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way than the two mentioned above?
2. With `at_exit` - is there a way to prevent any backtrace from showing, other than using `exit!`?

Reference code:

```
at_exit do
  if $! and $!.class != SystemExit
    show_errors $!
    exit! 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Perhaps. See how I did it in [`pretty_debug` gem](https://github.com/sawa/pretty_debug/blob/master/lib/pretty_debug.rb#L109#L121).
2. Yes. As I did in the link above, do:

   ```
   $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
   $stdout.reopen(IO::NULL)
   ```

Comment: Interesting. What does the `reopen` do? I understand it is there to prevent the original error from showing, not sure I get why it yields this result. (will try your gem).